# Django ListView not working on the template

Tags: django, listview, templates, django-queryset

I am trying for hours on a problem that seems very straightforward and I tried everything but it's not working.  I want to display the list of blogs on a template. So, I have these views:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Blog

class BlogList(generic.ListView):

    queryset = Blog.objects.filter()
    template_name = 'table_of_contents.html'
    context_object_name = 'blog_list'


class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):

    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog.html'
```

And this is the `table_of_contents.html` template where I want to display the list of blogs:

```
{% block table_of_contents %}
<p>Just for test</p>
{{ blog_list }}
{%endblock table_of_contents %}
```

I expect that would display the `queryset` string on the frontend, but that's not the case. I debugged BlogList using the Django shell and made sure that `queryset` was not empty.

What is the (obvious) detail that I am missing here?

Edit:
Here is the *blog.html* template as well:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<p>Test blog template</p>
{% block table_of_contents %} {% include 'table_of_contents.html' %} {% endblock table_of_contents %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Again, the querystring is not rendered at all, no matter if I use a for loop or just do `{{ blog_list }}`.

Comment: Can you share the "parent" template?

Comment: Ok, I added an edit to my question.

Comment: exact how does the *base* look like? Is there a block with `table_of_contents`?

Comment: No. In `base.html` I have `{% block content %} {% endblock content %}`. That's where `blog.html` is injected.
`

Comment: So, blog.html extends base.html and table_of_contents.html is supposed to be a sidebar in blog.html.

Comment: but your base template should define a `{% block table_of_contents %}`, basically if you *extent* a template, you can only fill in content by the subtemplate. This thus means that `base.html` needs to define a (possible empty) block that is then extended by the subtemplate. The subtemplate after all only overrides specific blocks.

Comment: see [*template ineritcan*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) for more details.

Comment: But by that logic, the tag `<p>Just for test</p>`  of table_of_contents.html would **not** be rendered. However, that is not the case. _Just for test_ is displayed, but not the queryset results.

Comment: that is because you use the `{% block content %}`  here, and that block *is* defined in the `base.html` based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The queryset will look like `<QuerySet …>`, so that will not render effectively on the page, since it will assume that `<QuerySet` as a HTML tag, not as content.

What you can do is *iterate* over the items in the `QuerySet`, and render these individually, for example:

```
{% block table_of_contents %}
  <p>Just for test</p>
  {% for blog in blog_list %}
    {{ blog.title }}
  {% endfor %}
{%endblock table_of_contents %}
```

of course here I assume that your `Blog` model has a `title` field. You might need to change this to a different field.

If you define a [**`{% block … %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#block) this means you need to *inherit* from a parent template that specifies a block with the name `table_of_contents`.

You thus need to have a parent template, for example:

```
<!-- parent.html -->
My page
{% block table_of_contents %}
{% endblock table_of_contents %}
```

in your template where you list the blogs, you thus then inherit from the `parent.html` page with the [**`{% extends … %}`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends):

```
{% extends 'path/to/parent.html' %}
{% block table_of_contents %}
  <p>Just for test</p>
  {% for <b>blog in blog_list</b> %}
    {{ blog<b>.title</b> }}
  {% endfor %}
{%endblock table_of_contents %}
```